# Web page not loading CSS. HTTP works, HTTPS does not

Tags: apache, https

I have an HTTPS-based site that loads CSS via HTML just fine, but not via HTTPS.

```
http://site/foo.css
```

... loads the asset fine. But...

```
https://site/foo.css
```

Does not. I get an Apache 502 error. The Apache access log shows:

```
[07/Nov/2018:10:17:20 -0800] "GET /foo.css HTTP/1.0" 200 95568 "-" ...
```

That tells me that it's trying to load my foo.css as HTTP even though I specified HTTPS.  Also note that while my browser gives a 502 error, I get a 200 response in the logs.

Seems like some sort of HTTPS misconfiguration but I'm not sure what. Help?

Comment: Help us help you.  Post your configuration here.  Explain how you got your certificate (self-signed, through CA, ...), put your `LogLevel debug` and post the results, show us a sample HTML page with the problem, ...  See [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: "That tells me that it's trying to load my foo.css as HTTP even though I specified HTTPS" — No, it doesn't. HTTPS is HTTP tunnelled via a secure connection. The syntax of the request doesn't change to mention the S.

Comment: "Seems like some sort of HTTPS misconfiguration but I'm not sure what." — It sounds like it, but you've not told us anything about how you configured HTTPS for your site.

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
//site/foo.css
```

instead of adding protocol when linking your css.

link everything with https as secure sites does not support mixed content.